# Feeding Simulated Input to Interactive CLI Program

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

I'm pretty new to bash so bear with me

I'm currently working on a way to automate the creation process of Alexa skills using the ask cli package.

The first step in that process is to run the "ask new" command, which is an interactive command that takes you through a few steps, it looks like this:

```
$ask new
Please follow the wizard to start your Alexa skill project ->
? Choose the programming language you will use to code your skill:  (Use arrow keys)
> NodeJS
  Python
  Java
```

```
? Choose a method to host your skill's backend resources:  (Use arrow keys)
> Alexa-hosted skills
  Host your skill code by Alexa (free).
  AWS with CloudFormation
  Host your skill code with AWS services and provision with AWS CloudFormation (requires AWS account)
  AWS Lambda Host your skill code on AWS Lambda (requires AWS account).
```

etc. etc.

My hope is that I can pipe in simulated input to the program to complete this wizard automatically.

From what I've been able to google I should be able to use
`printf "[input here]" | ask new`
to pipe in the input.

So I used a combination of arrow key code and newline characters in hopes to use this method, but it fails.

The desired input is:

```
1. Down Arrow
2. Enter
3. Down Arrow
4. Down Arrow
5. Enter
6. Enter
7. skill name (stored in $1)
8. Enter
9. Enter
```

And here is my script currently:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
skill=$1
 
echo creating $skill...
echo running ask new...
printf "\033[B\n\033[B\033[B\n\n$skill\n\n" | ask new
echo finished...
```

Here is the output:

```
$ ./create.sh name
creating name...
running ask new...
Please follow the wizard to start your Alexa skill project ->
? Choose the programming language you will use to code your skill:  Python
? Choose a method to host your skill's backend resources:  (Use arrow keys)
> Alexa-hosted skills
  Host your skill code by Alexa (free).
  AWS with CloudFormation
  Host your skill code with AWS services and provision with AWS CloudFormation (
requires AWS account)
  AWS Lambda
  Host your skill code on AWS Lambda (requires AWS account).
  ──────────────
  self-hosted and manage your own hosting finished...
```

The first commands seem to work (it makes the second selection on the first prompt as hoped for). But then it stops on the second prompt.

This may just have to do with some basic misunderstanding of bash, like I said I'm pretty new to it, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You might try `\r` as "hitting enter". If that fails, you may need to fall back to [tag:expect] which is ... less simple.

Comment: Unfortunately it's the same output using `\r`, I'll look into expect I guess :/

Comment: `then it stops on the second prompt.` add `sleep 1` between parts to let the code load. `{ sleep 1; print "<down><enter>"; sleep 1;  print <down><Down><enter> ;sleep 1; .... ; echo; } | ask new`. I _very much_ doubt it's a good idea to create such interface with writing "down" "up" do an interactive program. You _should_ instead interest yourself in `ask new --template=...` - ie. the native option to do it in non-interactive way. _For sure_ such a big company unit-tests their code and for sure the command can be run in non-interactive way.

Comment: @jjcurrado : Are you sure that `ask` reads from stdin? Since it prompts for using arrow keys, I don't think it does.

Comment: @KamilCuk yeah that's probably the way to go, thanks.

Comment: @user1934428 not entirely sure to be honest, that's a good point though.